# DataGrid columns do not refresh values with DataGrid2D

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datagridcolumnheader

I am trying to bind columns and rows of `DataGrid` to the same source but DataGrid does not show new value in the `ColumnHeader` when I change value in the `RowHeader` after `TextBox` lost focus. Headers collection contains new values as expected.

```
xmlns:dataGrid2D="http://gu.se/DataGrid2D"

<Grid>
    <DataGrid
        dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowHeadersSource="{Binding Headers}"
        dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding Headers}"
        dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.Array2D="{Binding Items}"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

DataContext:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Header> Headers { get; } = new Header[]
    { new Header { Value = "1" }, new Header { Value = "2" } };
    public string[,] Items { get; } = new string[2, 2] { { "1", "2" }, { "3", "4" } };
}
public class Header
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

I am changing the Value property from the View side so it does not need INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If I call "Refresh" on DataGrid it updates but with blinking.

Edit:

Why are you downvoting me? Is it a bad question?

Comment: The Value property does not fire a change notification when its value changes. You should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Clemens I am changing the Value property from the View side so it does not need INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If I call "Refresh" on DataGrid it updates but with blinking.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't call Refresh. Besides that, implementing INPC is necessary to communicate the change back from the view model to the view.

Comment: @Clemens I know it)) I do not need update value from view model here.

Comment: Ok, good luck then.

Comment: @Clemens thank you))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution using the style for `DataGridColumnHeader`. I also explicitly used the `Value` property instead of the `ToString` method.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid
    dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.RowHeadersSource="{Binding Headers}"
    dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding Headers}"
    dataGrid2D:ItemsSource.Array2D="{Binding Items}"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

You need to slightly change the ModelView then:

```
    public class Header: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Value;

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _Value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to give you upvote but it says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." So sorry about that as you was the only one who help me

Comment: I removed another question and now I have 15 reputation. Thank you again) I fight with this problem 3 days and finally it works.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution ;)